# Umatched braces in ASP.NET Web Pages C# code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, razor-2

The If Else block under "Connect to MPP and look for existing Driver IDs" is causing unmatched curly braces in my main Razor block.  I know I am missing something, but cannot figure it out.
Debugger is ignoring the last curly brace, seeing the next to last curly brace as matched with the @{ opening curly brace.

```
@{
Layout = "~/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
Page.Title = "Register";

// Setup field validation
Validation.RequireField("driverfirstname", "Cannot be blank.");
Validation.RequireField("driverlastname", "Cannot be blank.");
Validation.RequireField("driverssn", "Cannot be blank.");

// Initialize variables
var driverfirstname = "";
var driverlastname = "";
var driverssn = "";

// If validation is OK    
if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())
{
    driverfirstname = @Request.Form["driverfirstname"];
    driverlastname = @Request.Form["driverlastname"];
    driverssn = @Request.Form["driverssn"];

    // Create Driver ID and Password
    string first = driverfirstname.Substring(0, 3);
    string last = driverlastname.Substring(0, 3);
    string lastFour = driverssn.Substring(7, 4);
    string drivercodetest = (last + first).ToUpper();

    // Connect to MPP and look for existing Driver IDs
    var dbs = Database.Open("other_db");
    var drivercodempp = dbs.Query("SELECT mpp_id FROM profile WHERE mpp_id = @drivercodetest");
    var drivercode = "";

    if (drivercodempp == null)
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper();
    }
    else if (drivercodempp.Contains("01"))
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper() + "02";
    }
    else if (drivercodempp.Contains("02"))
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper() + "03";
    }
    else if (drivercodempp.Contains("03"))
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper() + "04";
    }
    else if (drivercodempp.Contains("04"))
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper() + "05";
    }
    else if (drivercodempp.Contains("05"))
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper() + "06";
    }
    else
    {
        drivercode = (last + first).ToUpper() + "07";
    }

    // Submit to database
    var dbi = Database.Open("MainDB");
    var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO driver (drivercode, driverfirstname, driverlastname, driverssn) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3)";
    dbi.Execute(insertCommand, drivercode, driverfirstname, driverlastname, driverssn);

    Response.Redirect("~/confirm_register");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your `if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())` line is missing its closing brace.

Comment: I checked that. I have two closing braces after "Response.Redirect...", one for the "IsPost..." and one for the Razor block.

Comment: Error 1 } expected c:\Users\indyitman\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\1a7fde3c\2913116c\App_Web_rt5b21nh.6.cs 2148

Comment: Open that generated `.cs` file in VS and have a look there. You might have other code causing problems. Brace-matching tends to have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue as well.
I think your issue is with your @Request variables.
Try getting rid of the @ sign in front of the variable name and it should resolve the issue for you.  You don't need the @ symbol when you are in @{} blocks (you can access Request directly), and apparently it actually causes the curly braces to get mismatched.  My guess is that the @ causes Razor's parser to get confused and exit the code block early.  Other syntax violations will cause it as well, so Dai's post is probably applicable too.

```
// If validation is OK    
if (IsPost && Validation.IsValid())
{
    driverfirstname = Request.Form["driverfirstname"];
    driverlastname = Request.Form["driverlastname"];
    driverssn = Request.Form["driverssn"];
```

You also have a couple more uses of @variable syntax that probably need to be resolved:

```
var drivercodempp = dbs.Query("SELECT mpp_id FROM profile WHERE mpp_id = @drivercodetest");
```

and

```
var insertCommand = "INSERT INTO driver (drivercode, driverfirstname, driverlastname, driverssn) VALUES(@0, @1, @2, @3)";
```

This last one you may need to encode the @ with @@ since you actually need the @ literal.
If I didn't catch all the syntax violations, then start cutting out large parts of the code and pasting them back in a line at a time till you find what is confusing the Razor parser.

A secondary issue is that much of this logic should probably be moved out of your view, into your controller or a repository to better follow the MVC pattern of separation of concerns.  But I think the root cause here is syntax issues are causing you to exit the Razor code block early.